# Inserting a single row in SQL, but loading the contents from a file

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I can `INSERT` a row into SQL like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (0, 'This is some text...');
```

However, what if I wanted *This is some text...* to be the contents of `C:\SomeFile.txt`.  Is there a method in Oracle that makes this possible?

I dug through the Docs a bit and found the `LOAD FILE` method, however it appears to be for bulk loading data.  For example, it wants a `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` parameter and what not.  I want to simply INSERT a single row and set a single column to by the contents of a file on the local disk.

Comment: Read the file in PHP (or whatever) and create the `INSERT` statements on the fly.

Comment: @MikeW - Yea, I just have one file so I'd rather not write a whole program for this heh..  But it might be the last resort.

Comment: There is no pure SQL solution for that (aAnd `LOAD FILE` is **not** an Oracle SQL statement either, so I don't know in which docs you found that). Some SQL clients offer proprietary extensions to do things like that though

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That looks like suspiciously like mysql

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_modes.htm#i1008815) - But I didn't read it carefully.  Maybe it's some special SQLPlus extension command?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Ah, yes it's a Oracle *utility* called SQL*Loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never be reading files from the DATABASE SERVER's file system to insert into the db.

Why do you want to do this? You really should read the file in your application code, then insert the string or binary data through standard SQL.

If you really must do this you will need to use the oracle [UTL_FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm) function. and write some PL/SQL to store in a variable, then insert.

Comment: We have some HTML templates that are currently on the file system, but we want to move them into the database.  Eventually (when we have time), there will be an admin feature to edit these templates, but for now I just want to get the data in the database.  So this is a one time thing.

Comment: Ah that makes sense if the database server is on the same machine as the web server and file storage. This would fail of course if the DB is a separate server. Sounds like a quick perl script might be the easiest way, otherwise you are stuck doing `UTL_FILE.GET_RAW` in a loop.

Comment: I ended up just using the Visual Studio Debugger window to do this, since everything was mapped with the ORM anyway.  Easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

My first time answering a question, so forgive me.

If you're using PHP (which you may well not be, but this is what I know), then you could do something like this:

File: "importantfile.php"

```
$variable 1 = "0";
$variable 2 = "This is some text...";
```

File that inserts text: "index.php"

```
require "importantfile.php";
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('$variable1', '$variable2')");
```

I hope this helps you in some way :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for a pure SQL way to do this.  Yea, I could write a quick C# or Python program to do this but I figured there might be some easier way.

Answer (score 1):

To do this I think you would have to use PL/SQL. This is technically an "advanced SQL".
search up a bit about PL/SQL. You can copy your SQL directly into PL/SQL and use the same database.